# Given edge e, what is the fastest way in Python to find the set of paths that contain e?

Tags: python, numpy

Say we are given a set of paths `P` (of same length) between a source and a sink and an edge `e`. In python, I represent this by a list of lists and a pair, i.e.,

```
# source = 0, sink = 9
# Path i is giving by P[i]: P[i][j] is the node j.
# Path i is giving then by the edges (P[i][0], P[i][1]), (P[i][1], P[i][2]), (P[i][2], P[i][3]), ...

P = [[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 
     [0, 1, 4, 6, 8, 9], 
     [0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9], 
     [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9],
     [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9]]
# The edge we are looking for is (1, 3)
e = (1, 3)
```

Since `e=(1, 3)` is contained in 3 paths, `P[0], P[2]`, and `P[3]`, the result is `3`.

Here is my solution:

```
def count_paths(edge, paths):
    count = 0
    for path in paths:
        edges = [(path[i], path[i + 1]) for i in range(len(path) - 1)]
        if edge in edges:
            count += 1
    return count
```

When the number of paths is large, this function gives `tottime` of `16.245` using `cProfile`. Can we make it run faster, using numpy for example?

Comment: Is P always a regular array that is same number of elements per "row"?

Comment: Yes, all paths have the same length.

Comment: since you are using python then to obtain sligthly more speed you can use `numpy` as your set of paths can be converted easily to a `numpy ndarray`, and then you get less latency when trying to access it's elements. (for more optimization the set of edges store it also in a ndarray.

Comment: Path like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8]` won't be counted in, right?

Comment: No, it won't be counted. A path `[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 8]` is given by the edges `(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 6), (6, 8)`, so edge `(1,3)` is not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to array, slice it with one-off offsets to look for sink start and stop values along each row and then simply sum the counts for our desired output, all in a vectorized manner -

```
In [43]: P = np.array(P)

In [44]: ((P[:,:-1]==1) & (P[:,1:]==3)).sum()
Out[44]: 3
```

If you need the valid paths too, mask the array with `ANY` reduced row-mask -

```
In [16]: P[((P[:,:-1]==1) & (P[:,1:]==3)).any(1)]
Out[16]: 
array([[0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9],
       [0, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9],
       [0, 1, 3, 5, 8, 9]])
```